# Certificate error while setting SSL enabled for my Asp.Net MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl-certificate

When I run the project with SSL I get a warning in the browser, in every browser: firefox, IE, edge, chrome. When I launch the project it doesn't show me the warning dialog and I don't know if I have any certificate installed.

How to check if I have the certificate installed and if not, how to install it?

Comment: You have to check in IIS...the is an option called "Server Certificates"

Comment: and there what to do?

Comment: "This CA Root certificate is not trusted because it is not in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store." it says @Hackerman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to add your certificate to CA Root.

High level plan:

1. Export SSL certificate from IIS.
2. Import that SSL certificate into CA Root.

Here is [a blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robert_mcmurray/2013/11/15/how-to-trust-the-iis-express-self-signed-certificate/) that explains everything in detail and with screenshots.

If you use Google Chrome, you might need to close and re-open it after installing a new SSL certificate due to browser's caching.

Comment: for those who got the Certificate deleted or are missing it, just go to the Uninstall Programs in your Control Panel and repair IIS expres

Answer (score 1):

You can use [online SSL checker tool](https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/ssl-installation-checker/) to diagnoses issues regarding SSL certificate installation.

You should check that you are using a self-signed certificate or a CA signed certificate. If it’s a self-signed certificate then your users will experience warning message when they browse your site because browsers don't recognize it.

If you have a CA signed certificate, then you received a certificate via email from trusted third-party certificate authority, which contains the root, intermediate and primary certificates. You should install all three files on your server.

You should update your all browser. Modern browsers have already implemented root certificate, so you need to configure only intermediate and primary certificate on the server.

Follow below link which may help you to add CA Root certificate in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities store. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754841(v=ws.11).aspx